Limiting input current of buck converter
I am using a TPS5430 buck converter connected to a power supply that can output up to 200mA at 12V. When I try to draw more current (around 250mA), the voltage drops significantly. The issue is that the inrush current is too high, which prevents the converter from starting properly. I have tried to connect it to a supply without current limitations. The device consumes around 180mA in steady state. Output voltage of buck is 6V.
What would be the best way to limit the inrush current in this case? Are there any recommended components or techniques (e.g., external soft-start, resistors) that could help, considering the use of the TPS5430?


Inductor is 47uH

I have tried to connect it to a supply without current limitations. <-- what happened?

@Andy aka It works. Unfortunately, I cannot measure the inrush current, but the steady current is around 180mA

Typical application (§ 7.2 of datasheet) should be 220 uF and L1 = 15 uH.

That device already has built in in-rush current limiting, so it's possible the issue is the 10uF input cap if you're switching everything on at once. You should get a scope and measure what's really going on

So the load is about 330mA? That's quite a lot for such a feeble supply. It seems to me, something has been overlooked in the overall system design, and the more interesting question is in regards to that.

You have very less output capacitance. 6V with typical slow start at 6mS, with 10uF Cout, Inrush will be 10mA, You should not see that much Inrush unless internal slow start circuit is not working as intended. IC has UVLO also ~5.3V.I suggest reduce your L, increase Cout. Consider internal compensation data. for value calcualtions.
